# Communication issues with Python gRPC client and server in k8s cluster

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes, grpc

**Update: On my client application, I used the server's IP address directly and it worked. Now, I need to figure out why I am unable to connect using DNS names.**

**Update #2: After following DazWilkin's suggestions, I was able to establish a connection using an insecure channel between client and server without relying on IP addresses. This is what I did:**

1. I removed the k8s ingress from the equation and instead used the server's service DNS name: {service}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local
2. I set my server application's k8s service's port and targetPort to use the port running the gRPC server (9000)
3. On my client, I set the GRPC_SERVER_ADDRESS variable as: <server's k8s service DNS name>:<server's port>

**Original Post**

I am trying to create a simple gRPC client/server in Python, but I am unable to establish a connection between the two parts. Both my client and server applications are running in separate k8s namespaces within the same network. Both also have an ingress, a service, and a dnsservice for communication purposes.

Obs.: The k8s service on both applications maps port 80 to port 9000.

Here's the relevant snippet of code for my client:

```
# client.py

GRPC_SERVER_ADDRESS = "grpc-server.com"


@image_bp.route('/image-grpc', methods=['POST'])
def modify_image_grpc():
    request_json = request.get_json()
    with grpc.insecure_channel(GRPC_SERVER_ADDRESS) as channel:
        stub = image_pb2_grpc.ImageServiceStub(channel)
        image = stub.GetImage(image_pb2.ImageRequest(
            id_user=request_json['id_user'],
        ))
    
    # response = ...

    return response
```

And here is the relevant code snippet for my server:

```
# server.py

GRPC_MAX_WORKERS = 10
GRPC_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
GRPC_PORT = "9000"


def serve():
    try:
        server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=GRPC_MAX_WORKERS))
        image_pb2_grpc.add_ImageServiceServicer_to_server(ImageService(), server)
        server.add_insecure_port(f'{GRPC_HOST}:{GRPC_PORT}')
        server.start()
        server.wait_for_termination()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'[-] Error serving gRPC on port {GRPC_PORT}: {e}')
        sys.exit()
```

And here is the error message produced in my client application whenever I try to send a request:

```
# client.error.log

<_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1662987231.739227750","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file
_line":3260,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1662987231.739227058","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc","file_lin
e":167,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

... (line in my code that raises the exception: stub.GetImage)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1662987231.739227750","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file
_line":3260,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1662987231.739227058","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc","file_lin
e":167,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

Package versions:

```
# requirements.txt

...

grpcio==1.47.0
grpcio-tools==1.47.0

...
```

I have seen some solutions online that utilize a secure channel, but I intend on using an insecure channel. Any ideas?

Comment: One way to debug this is to start with the simplest possible configuration and then add complexity (layers of abstraction) until you either find the problem or realize the error. The simplest way to test your solution is to run the server (!) locally and use a known-working tool like [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to call a method implemented by the server. If this works, then try using your existing client (again locally). If that works, then try deploying the service to the Kubernetes cluster but run the client locally etc. etc.

Comment: Given that both client and server appear destined to run within the cluster, using `Ingress` resources may be overkill and is possibly the problem. If you deploy the client and server to the cluster, you can connect the client to the server using a cluster local DNS name (`{service}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local` name). If you deploy the client locally, you can expose the server (`Service`) externally (e.g. as a `ClusterIP` or `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`) without using an `Ingress`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try removing the Ingress from the equation.

Comment: I tried connecting using the cluster local DNS name, but the same error occurred =/

Comment: Are you including the server's port in the connection that you're using on the client? There is no default port value with gRPC and so one will always be required.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!